# function template does not recognize lvalue

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lvalue, rvalue

I have a problem in my code

Here is simplified version of it :

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
public :
    template <class T>
    void func(T&&)//accept rvalue
    {
        std::cout<<"in rvalue\n";
    }

    template <class T>
    void func(const T&)//accept lvalue
    {
        std::cout<<"in lvalue\n";
    }
};
int main() 
{    
    A a;
    double n=3;
    a.func(n);
    a.func(5);
}
```

I expect the output to be :

```
in lvalue
in rvalue
```

but it is

```
in rvalue 
in rvalue
```

why ?!

Comment: Hint: what's the difference between both parameters, aside the `&`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`template <class T> void func(T&&)` is <strike>*universal reference*</strike> *forwarding reference*.

To test what you want, try: ([Live example](https://ideone.com/DN7eJL))

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    void func(T&&)//accept rvalue
    {
        std::cout<<"in rvalue\n";
    }
    void func(T&)//accept lvalue
    {
        std::cout<<"in lvalue\n";
    }
};

int main() 
{    
    A<double> a;
    double n = 3;
    a.func(n);
    a.func(5.);
}
```

Comment: Maybe "universal reference" should be in quotes, since it is not a language construct.

Comment: @juanchopanza Technically, it is a language construct, just that "universal reference" is not its official name. I quite wish it were, though.

Comment: It is now called *"forwarding reference"*.

Answer (score 6):

To build on Jarod42's fine answer, if you want to keep the design of having a primary function template, you can decide based on the deduced type of the universal reference parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    template <typename T>                 // T is either U or U &
    void func(T && x)
    {
        func_impl<T>(std::forward<T>(x));
    }

    template <typename U>
    void func_impl(typename std::remove_reference<U>::type & u)
    {
        std::cout << "lvalue\n";
    }

    template <typename U>
    void func_impl(typename std::remove_reference<U>::type && u)
    {
        std::cout << "rvalue\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the surprise comes from the way the template argument are deduced. You'll get what you expect if you write:

```
a.func<double>(n);
```

Comment: I think you mean "how function template arguments are deduced".

Comment: Yes ! I realized that I don't fully understand what's going on here. I asked a followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167235/understanding-template-argument-deduction-with-rvalue-lvalue